Is the g tensor always "parallel" to the (hyperfine) A tensor?
I have a question about the anisotropy of the g tensor and the A tensor (hyperfine splitting tensor) in electron paramagnetic resonance (EPR).
Both tensors are symmetric, and as a result, there is for each tensor a set of axes (principal axes) for which the tensors are diagonal.
Is it always true, for all chemical species in all media, that the g tensor and A tensor are "parallel" in the sense that their principal axes are in the same direction? Or can the principal axes of the two tensors be in completely different directions?
